# Application of Implementing 3 Stacks in single array

Tags: applications, stack, implementations

Well, there is lot of discussion about implementing 3 (or 2 stacks) in a single array. But whats the **real need or application** for implementing stacks like that?

Can't we allot memory as 3 separate stacks [array] itself? Anyway we are alloting `array[size * 3]` in that single array.

some links that discuss some:

- [Use an array to implement three Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239292/use-an-array-to-implement-three-stack)
- [how to implement 3 stack in a single array efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397344/how-to-implement-3-stack-in-a-single-array-)

Answer (score 4):

Many interview questions serve no practical purpose. They are a challenge to see if you can think your way through something difficult. People who ask them believe they serve as a good substitute for the genuinely difficult challenges in their coding that cannot be explained in such a short time (and whose solutions cannot be evaluated so quickly either.)

In Physics there's a story about the question "how would you measure the height of a building with a barometer?" The "right" answer involves measuring the air pressure at the top and bottom and applying a formula. My favourite "wrong" answers involve dropping it from the top, measuring the time till it hits the ground, and applying a formula, or seeking out the architect/janitor/owner of the building and offering a trade: I'll give you this expensive barometer if you tell me how tall that building is.

The point of the question wasn't that people need to measure height with barometers regularly (or ever) but to see if the candidate knew the formula for pressure and height. Similarly your question will test if you know how to manage memory, restructure a simple approach (stacks) to handle a strange constraint, and think about clever things like not moving the item from stack to stack but just updating the links. While there may be some strange edge case like "each stack can have up to a million items, but when one grows the others shrink so the total space never changes" that happen in the real world, that is not why you're being asked to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing multiple stacks in a single (linked list) array could use memory more efficiently.

If you have three stacks in three separate arrays, each one would need pre-allocated space to allow for future elements, and each one would need new memory to be allocated if it fills up.  Combining them to a single array would reduce the amount of "extra" memory that is pre-allocated for future operations, and you would have to allocate new memory fewer times.

However, the stacks in a single array would also be more complicated to manage.  Elements of the three stacks will be interspersed with each other.  When elements are removed from one stack, it may leave gaps.  You then need to be able to search and fill these gaps later on when you add a new element.

With the amount of memory typically available these days, combining stacks in this way would be a rather extreme optimization.  Rarely would you even think of doing this.  But it might be useful occasionally.

**Update:** It would be most useful in certain specialized cases.  If you have a situation in which you will frequently move elements between stacks, storing the stacks in a single array would be more efficient.  Moving element X from stack A to stack B would only require changing the links.

Comment: Anyway total size 'll be same right? are you saying extra memory as pointer (head of 3 stacks)?

Comment: @Dineshkumar, if you have three stacks, each with a preallocated array, then each array needs extra empty space at the end to allow for future elements.  If you only have one array, then you only have one block of empty space, potentially saving memory.